# ubuntu pdo_sqlserv not installing after lot of setup

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I tried following

1st series of steps

1.

```
sudo apt-get install vim curl git zip unzip htop apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

2.

```
curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
sudo apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
```

3.

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc g++ make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

4.

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo bash -c "echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

5.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

////////////////

2nd series of steps

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
echo "extension=sqlsrv" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

extensions in php.ini

```
extension=sqlsrv
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
```

then restart xampp and ubuntu again .still no output . I specifically want sqlserv with pdo 
what stepam i missing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified which Ubuntu version you use. You didn't also say what errors you got.
In that case is difficult to troubleshoot. However I would go step by step with Microsoft guide. I used it many times and it never failed.

[Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ok , i will check this link and try to specify where is the issue